# Show progress of a Matlab instruction execution

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to show the execution progress (even a rough estimation) of a Matlab instruction?

For example let's say I am computing distances using pdist:

```
D = pdist(my_matrix,'cosine');
```

and this computation takes hours, does Matlab provide any way to show periodically the execution progress?

Comment: Within a single instruction (and in real time), I don't think so.

Comment: you could modify pdist and look for for-loops and add waitbars :)

Comment: @Benoit_11      isn't that hacking MATLAB's native library of .m functions :p

Comment: @hagubear yeah I'm afraid it is :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not intrinsically. You can of course do after-the-fact checking with the profiler or tic/toc.

If this is something you will be doing a lot for a single function, you could consider modifying the function and saving it in your path with a new name (I have a directory called "Modified Builtin" for just this purpose). In the case of `pdist.m`, you might save `pdist_updates.m`. Looking a the function, the actual distances are calculated starting around line 250 with a series of nested loops. Add in a line like:

```
disp(sprintf('Processing pair %d of %d',i,n-1));
```

at line 265. If you really wanted to get fancy, you could use `tic` and `toc` to time each loop and provide an estimate of how long the entire calculation would take so you would know how long you had to run to the coffee machine.

Of course this will cause problems if you end up cancelling your Statistics Toolbox license or if Mathworks upgrades the toolbox and changes the functionality, so use this approach sparingly.